# kstart detailed description

Tags: kubuntu, kde, startup

I'm having trouble getting `kstart` to work properly, so I'm looking for a much more detailed description of its behavior than what I can get from its manpage.  Although the manpage describes all the parameters, all it says about its general functioning is "Utility to launch applications with special window properties."  For instance, when does the calling shell regain control -- immediately or after some other actions are performed?  What if any is the difference in behavior between `kstart` and `kstart &`?

I want to use `kstart` to start firefox, konsole, and kmail in desktops 1, 2, and 3 upon startup.  (I'm running Kubuntu 14.10.)  I tried including this as a startup script:

```
kstart --desktop 1 firefox
kstart --desktop 2 konsole
kstart --desktop 3 kmail
```

(I used System Setup/Autostart to install it.)  The result was that my system hung solidly.  So I tried this instead:

```
#! /bin/sh
kstart --desktop 1 firefox &
kstart --desktop 2 konsole &
kstart --desktop 3 kmail &
exit
```

I tried several other variations, most of which did not hang but nonetheless put all three programs onto the same desktop.

How can I get kstart to behave itself?

Answer (score 1):

**Ampersand &**

Special characters: http://uw714doc.sco.com/en/SDK_tools/_Special_Characters.html

> Running a command in background with the ampersand
>
> Some shell commands take a long time to execute. The ampersand (``&'')
>   is used to execute commands in background mode, thus freeing your
>   terminal for other tasks. The general format for running a command in
>   background mode is
>
> command &

**kstart --help**

The kstart has the help:

```
:~$ kstart --help
Usage: kstart [Qt-options] [KDE-options] [options] command 

Utility to launch applications with special window properties 
such as iconified, maximized, a certain virtual desktop, a special decoration
and so on.

Generic options:
  --help                    Show help about options
  --help-qt                 Show Qt specific options
  --help-kde                Show KDE specific options
  --help-all                Show all options
  --author                  Show author information
  -v, --version             Show version information
  --license                 Show license information
  --                        End of options

Arguments:
  command                   Command to execute

Options:
  --service <desktopfile>   Alternative to <command>: desktop file to start. D-Bus service will be printed to stdout
  --url <url>               Optional URL to pass <desktopfile>, when using --service
  --window <regexp>         A regular expression matching the window title
  --windowclass <class>     A string matching the window class (WM_CLASS property)
                            The window class can be found out by running
                            'xprop | grep WM_CLASS' and clicking on a window
                            (use either both parts separated by a space or only the right part).
                            NOTE: If you specify neither window title nor window class,
                            then the very first window to appear will be taken;
                            omitting both options is NOT recommended.
  --desktop <number>        Desktop on which to make the window appear
  --currentdesktop          Make the window appear on the desktop that was active
                            when starting the application
  --alldesktops             Make the window appear on all desktops
  --iconify                 Iconify the window
  --maximize                Maximize the window
  --maximize-vertically     Maximize the window vertically
  --maximize-horizontally   Maximize the window horizontally
  --fullscreen              Show window fullscreen
  --type <type>             The window type: Normal, Desktop, Dock, Toolbar, 
                            Menu, Dialog, TopMenu or Override
  --activate                Jump to the window even if it is started on a 
                            different virtual desktop
  --ontop, --keepabove      Try to keep the window above other windows
  --onbottom, --keepbelow   Try to keep the window below other windows
  --skiptaskbar             The window does not get an entry in the taskbar
  --skippager               The window does not get an entry on the pager
```

But as noted in the Bug 57575 - Multiple asynchronous "kstart --desktop" place launched apps on random desktops : https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=57575 it should say more clearly that the window/windowclass is not optional if there is more than one window.

This is working at here:

```
#! /bin/sh
kstart --desktop 1 --windowclass Firefox firefox
kstart --desktop 2 --windowclass Konsole konsole
kstart --desktop 3 --windowclass Kmail kmail
```